# When and when not to use createAppContainer?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a project where i am using different navigation like drawer tabs etc. My question is when should i use `createAppContainer` and when not, because if i wrap my root navigator with `createAppContainer` like `export default createAppContainer(RootTabNavigator);` or if i don't wrap in `createAppContainer` like `export default RootTabNavigator;` in both scenarios they work the same because on the other screen i am already using `createAppContainer` for drawer navigation. **so what are the benifits for using it and when should i use it and should i also use `createAppContainer` in my tabNavigation?**

Comment: you just need one createAppContainer which will wrap your rootStack.

Comment: i have different navigations which one should i wrap and which not?

Comment: share your code for better understanding.